# How to create a button that downloads a file in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, download

I have a button and a calendar in my html that when the user clicks the button it Downloads a file from a file path and if the user picks a particular date it will download that file. My problem was, instead of downloading the file in the webpage it displays the file in the web browser. How can I resolve this issue? Thank you.. I've also added the images at the bottom.

```
    public ActionResult Download(DateTime? downloaddate)
      {
          if (downloaddate == null)
        {
            string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "logs/";
            string filename2 = "industrialcomm-payload-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log";
            byte[] filebytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path + filename2);
            string contentType = "text/plain";


            return File(filebytes, contentType);
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime Date = new DateTime();
            Date = (DateTime)downloaddate;

            string path1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "logs/";
            string filename = "industrialcomm-payload-" + Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log";
            byte[] filebytes1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path1 + filename);
            string contentType1 = "text/plain";

            return File(filebytes1, contentType1);
        }


     @using (Html.BeginForm("Download", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
      {
         <input type="date" id="myDate" data-date-format="YYYY DD MMMM" value=""name="downloaddate" style="border:medium; ">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" style="font-size:larger; font-weight:bolder;">Download Log</button> 



      }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out what's causing the problem.
On the `return File`, I forgot to include `filename2` and `filename`. After adding those variables, it fixed the problem.

```
return File(filebytes, contentType, filename2);
```